# explain all the steps codes that will be executed one by one

Tags: r

```
    f<-function(x)       #build the first function f()#
    {
      f<-function(x)     #define the second function f()  within  first ##f() function##
      {
        f<-function(x)   #define the third function f() within the ##second f() function and within the first f() function ##      
        {
        x^2       #within the second function of f we define a variable ##f, i.e.f(x)=x^2 ##           
        } 
        f(x)+1    #within the first function f we define another variable f, i.e.f(x)=x^2+1#            
      }
      f(x)+2# R looking for the second varible f it takes the defintion of f as varible within the first function of f()#i.e.(x^2+1)+2 
    }              
    f(10)

## 10^2=100, 100+1=101, 101+2=103
## ((10^2)+1)+2=103
```

I tried to explain the codes step by step and how these codes running to one by one to get the final output but not sure if it is right or not

Answer (score 0):

```
##defining the function f(g(h(x)))
##f(x) = g(x) + 2; g(x) = h(x) + 1; h(x) = x^2
f <- function ( x ) {
    g <- function ( x ) {
        h <- function ( x ) {
            x ^ 2 ##computing h(x)
        }
        h(x) + 1 ##computing g(x)
    }
    return(g(x) + 2) ##returning final output; computing f(x)
}

f(10)
> 103
```

This is how I would have done it. I think you're explanations are a little lengthy and defining f as more than one function is typically a bad idea. If you are dead set on using f as the function name add a number afters. `f1`, `f2`, `f3`.